# Google Cloud Vm Instance doesn't let me send emails with phpmailer using a gsuite account

Tags: php, virtual-machine, phpmailer

I need to send emails in my webapp and I use phpmailer for that.
It works perfectly in my localhost but when running it into my Vm Instance in google cloud it doesn't send the email and phpmailer doesn't throw any error.

I already tried by allowing 465,25,2525,487 ports for outgoing traffic on the firewall rules. And i've changed the phpmailer port smtp from 25 to 487 but it stills without working.

The account i'm using for sending the email is a gSuite account with my custom domain.

And I don't want to use thirdy part platforms like sendgrid of that stuff.

I would really appreciate your help! Thanks.

```
    public $From     = 'mydomain@domain.com';
    public $FromName = "X";
    public $Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    public $Mailer   = 'smtp';
    public $SMTPAuth = true;
    public $Username = 'mydomain@domain.com';
    public $Password = 'mypassword';
    public $SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    public $WordWrap = 75;
```

Comment: port 587 for tls

Comment: @Farkie Just changed it, doesn't work neither.

Comment: Use the tests described in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) to diagnose your problem. It's likely that it's blocking outbound SMTP; that's very common.

Comment: @Synchro Why would it block the outbound smtp if all the ports are enabled?

Comment: @Synchro Just checked, not a single error message.

Comment: They might be enabled on your server, but that doesn't mean that the network your VM is on allows outbound SMTP. SMTP blocking is really common with cloud hosting providers.

Comment: Not even a "connection failed" or timing out with `SMTPDebug = 3`? What happens when you telnet out to SMTP ports on external servers (as the guide suggests trying)?

Comment: [Google's docs say they block port 25](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/), but allow others. You need to do those tests.

Comment: @Synchro I enabled the ports on the google firewall rules. And im not using the port 25, Im using the 587 and it doesnt work neither. I don't get any error neither.

Comment: So what did it say when you did `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`? (you may need to install telnet first). If it does nothing, followed by a timeout, your connection is being blocked.

Comment: @Synchro Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP l2sm30786194ioh.20 - gsmtp

Comment: That's a good sign - it shows that it's not being blocked. Now what happens when you do the same using PHPMailer with `SMTPDebug = 2`? It might help if you posted your complete code - it looks like you may be using an old version of PHPMailer.

Comment: @Synchro Blank page, which means not errors. The thing here is that im using it at my localhost and works perfectly. When i use it on google cloud it doesnt work. So its a problem at google cloud. I already changed the port that phpmailer uses for smtp and allowed that por on google cloud firewall rules but nothing seems to work. Im gonna lose my mind hahaha.

Comment: A blank page certainly does *not* mean "no errors"; on the contrary - it usually means you've had a fatal error. Enable PHP error display or check your web server logs. Your local and GC environments are different, as are the networks they are on.

Comment: I have php errors activated, when I get an error it shows it to me. That's why i said that.

Comment: If you don't post your code, we can't tell what you're doing.